# What operations can replace the boolean `and`?

Tags: logic

I want to extend a logical equation to allow for fractional values instead of just 1 and 0, such as 0.2 or 0.75.  The only requirement is that it works with 1 and 0 as though it is a logical "and": $\land$.

Logical and:
$1 \land 1 = 1 \\
1 \land 0 = 0 \\
0 \land 1 = 0 \\
0 \land 0 = 0 \\
1 \land 0.2 = \text{null}$

Multiplication:
$1 \times 1 = 1 \\
1 \times 0 = 0 \\
0 \times 1 = 0 \\
0 \times 0 = 0 \\
1 \times 0.2 = 0.2 \qquad \leftarrow \text{I don't care about the specific value, just that it exists.}$

Another operation that works is geometric mean, which takes the root of the multiplication.  I'd like to test out as many other options as possible, but I can't find a resource that lists logical operators with algebraic operations that work the same way.

I have found that multiplication works, and that the result of the multiplication can be re-scaled, provided that 0 and 1 are unchanged (like with powers). What else can I do?

Comment: Here's a recent similar (not identical) question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3314100/continuous-extension-of-xor/3314280#3314280.

Comment: You could use a 'binary and', which would work (theoretically at least) on any real numbers x and y: expand them in base 2, compute the 'and' of each pair of bits at the same position, you get the binary expansion of a real number. There is a twist with numbers which have two possible binary expansions (any number with finitely many 1 bits), but this can be dealt with by chosing one of them.

Comment: If you want to "test out as many operations as possible", it must because you hope to find one that turns out to have some particular *additional* properties you need. If you reveal what you're looking for, people would be able to help you much better rand random guessing.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, point well-taken, it's just that I don't really need any particular additional properties, and I figured for a Stack Exchange question, it would be better to keep it as simple as possible.  Also, I don't really know how to simply state the additional aspects without copy/pasting my whole project haha... guess I should work on my elevator pitch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility of extension is to consider the minimum function.

$$\min(1,1)=1$$

$$\min(x, 0)=0$$

if $x$ is binary.

Also, another possibility is to use the indicator function if the sum is more than $1.5$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are looking for is a fuzzy logic extension of the logical operator AND. Those extensions are called *t-norm*, and you can search e.g. Wikipedia for this term. Examples of t-norms are

- product norm: a*b
- Gödel norm:  min(a,b)
- Łukasiewicz t-norm: max(0,a+b-1)
- etc.

The fuzzy extensions of OR are called *t-conorm*.  (e.g. a+b-ab)

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @SiongThyeGoh's answer, propositions form dual semilattices under $\land$ and $\lor$, which motivates taking $x\land y:=\min\{x,\,y\}$ and $x\lor y:=\max\{x,\,y\}$. One advantage of this over definitions such as $x\land y:=xy$ is we achieve $x\land x=x$.

Comment: That's a great point!  I had to read it a few times to understand it haha.. It turns out that $x \land x = x$ may actually be undesirable in my case, and your expansion will help me describe ultimately which equation I choose.  Once I get 15 rep, I'll come back and upvote this answer!